# Как определить входит ли дата в интервал дат?

Tags: pandas, datetime

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить задачу?

Даны два сета данных:

Первый:

```
Start   End
01.03.2018  30.11.2018
01.06.2018  30.11.2018
```

характеристика первого сета:

```
Дата завершения        29051 non-null datetime64[ns]
Дата начала            29051 non-null datetime64[ns]
```

Второй:

```
Document_date
10.02.2018
10.02.2018
13.06.2018
13.06.2018
29.03.2018
19.04.2018
13.06.2018
20.03.2018
13.06.2018
25.01.2018
15.05.2018
19.04.2018
```

характеристика второго сета:

```
Дата документа            266193 non-null datetime64[ns]
Дилер                     266193 non-null object
Клиент (название)         266193 non-null object
Код товара                266193 non-null object
Количество в документе    266193 non-null float64
Регион клиента            266193 non-null object
Товар                     266193 non-null object
Month                     266193 non-null object
Year                      266193 non-null object
Система                   266193 non-null object
```

Посдкажите, пожалуйста, как эффективнее сделать проверку на вхождение дат из второго сета в интервал дат первого сета? На практике эти сеты размером около 200 т.строк и 10 полей.

Comment: Насколько большой первый сет? И что значит 10 полей? Вы хотите проверять сразу 10 полей во втором сете?

Comment: MaxU, добрый день! Сделал update.

Comment: прошу прощения, я сейчас занят - вечером попробую ответить...

Comment: MaxU, нашел решение. Позже отвечу на свой вопрос.

Comment: не совсем понятно что вы хотите получить на выходе...